# Eclipse 3.8 plug-in with Ecl4.4: missing constraint import package

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop an Eclipse Plug-In. Originally it was used for Eclipse 3.8. Now Im trying to start it with Eclipse 4.4.
So I changed the target platform from 3.8 to "running platform" and in the run-config I added my package
and then validated/added required platforms multiple times.

I've only some messages left now:

org.eclipse.jdt.annotation
    Missing Constraint: BundleRequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
and
Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.sirius.ext.emf

I know how I can add a plug-in to a run configuration, but not how to handle this missing package. 
I guess there might be a problem with the build path?
If it would be a normal project ok, but how do I find the build-path variable or so for this "running plattform" eclipse-product?

Or maybe the package is really missing? I guess I only have to look for it in the build path? If its there it must be ok?

I also read that it is possible that I have the wrong JRE. (actually: Runtime JRE: 1.7) 
The problem is that the Plug-In was build for Java 7. Is the annotation message the problem that he know can't resolve the 
missing package somehow? Or can I maybe ignore that? Im not sure if my package will work the right way with Java 8 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two versions of the `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation` plugin, one for Java 1.5 - 1.7 and the other for Java 1.8. If you aren't using Java 1.8 to other version will be used. So that message is OK.

The plugin `org.eclipse.sirius.ext.emf` looks like it is part of [Eclipse Sirius](http://eclipse.org/sirius/) so you probably need that installed.